# Regain Angular Scope

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have one table in which I am showing all the data. 
After table bind I applied [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com) plugin.

After that ng-click is not working for that table.

I think this due to that plugin scope object is not working.

How can I get the $scope so that all the other functionality will work fine?

Is there any method in which we can use the plugin and the $scope will not loss?

**Edit**

HTML Code:

```
<table id="tblChangeOrder" class="table">
                    <thead class="table-header-style">
                        <tr>
                            <th data-ng-click="loadChangeOrdersBySort('OrderControlNum')" class="hand" data-sidx="OrderControlNum" style="min-width:60px;">
                                CO#
                                <span data-ng-if="changeOrderSearch.Sidx == 'OrderControlNum'" class="move-right">
                                    <span data-ng-class="changeOrderSearch.Sord == 'asc' ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'"></span>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th data-ng-click="loadChangeOrdersBySort('RequestedBy')" class="hand" data-sidx="RequestedBy">
                                Requested By
                                <span data-ng-if="changeOrderSearch.Sidx == 'RequestedBy'" class="move-right">
                                    <span data-ng-class="changeOrderSearch.Sord == 'asc' ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'"></span>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th data-ng-click="loadChangeOrdersBySort('CustomerPo')" class="hand" data-sidx="CustomerPo">
                                PO#
                                <span data-ng-if="changeOrderSearch.Sidx == 'CustomerPo'" class="move-right">
                                    <span data-ng-class="changeOrderSearch.Sord == 'asc' ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'"></span>
                                </span>
                            </th>
</tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="table-body-style">
                        <tr data-ng-repeat="changeOrderData in changeOrders">
                            <td><a href="ChangeOrders.aspx?id={{changeOrderData.Id}}">{{changeOrderData.Id}}</a></td>
                            <td>
                                <span>{{changeOrderData.ReqName}}
                                <span data-ng-if="changeOrderData.RequesterID != changeOrderData.CreatorID">Entered By:{{changeOrderData.CreName}}
                                </span>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td><span>{{changeOrderData.PoNum}}</span></td>
</tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

JS Plugin Code:

```
$('#tblChangeOrder').tablesorter({
        showProcessing: true,
        widgets: ['scroller'],
        widgetOptions: {
            // scroll tbody to top after sorting
            //scroller_upAfterSort: true,

            // pop table header into view while scrolling up the page
            scroller_jumpToHeader: false,

            scroller_height: 400,

            // set number of columns to fix
            scroller_fixedColumns: 1,

            // add a fixed column overlay for styling
            scroller_addFixedOverlay: false,

            // add hover highlighting to the fixed column (disable if it causes slowing)
            //scroller_rowHighlight: 'hover',

            // bar width is now calculated; set a value to override
            scroller_barWidth: null
        },
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: false, filter: false },
            1: { sorter: false, filter: false },
            2: { sorter: false, filter: false }
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you please show the html and controller code ?

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is going on with out seeing some snipet of code

Comment: you need to sort data, instead of DOM.

Comment: @dennyjohn Updated the question can you please check

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that changes in DOM outside angular scope life-cyale because of your plugin.
So you should use [Angular + DataTable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) instead of using Jquery table sorter plugin.

Comment: this is client requirement we can't use any other plugin. I am using this plugin to FIX the 1st column of the grid for mobile version.

Comment: Yes, you are right, as I am updating the DOM outside angular scope that why scope is not working after update. Is there any method to fix this

Comment: You can invoke function form $scope of any element using 
`angular.element( document.getElementById('id') ).scope().func()`
But it is not good way because, Angular will have no track about what happened in that function execution.